# Video embedding inside beamer without Adobe Flash Player

Tags: flash, video, latex, embed, beamer

Good morning.

I need to embed a video inside a beamer presentation that is visible in Adobe Reader without using Adobe Flash Player.

As a minimal example, I used this snippet of code and it doesn't work. it only shows a black box:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\mode<presentation> {\usetheme{Madrid}}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{movie15}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{figure}[ht]
    \includemovie[poster,text={\includegraphics[width=8cm, height=6cm]
        {candp.png}},autoplay,mouse=true]{8cm}{6cm}
    {IMG_3746.wmv}
\end{figure}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

I'm opened to change the video format of my file to any format that works.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try either as MP4 or maybe FLV format. There are online converters if you need to change the WMV into something else.