# Output LaTeX code to a file format that can embed videos

Tags: latex, file-type, beamer

Which file format can I compile my LaTeX code (Beamer) to that works with slide shows and supports embedding videos? I know you could use PDFs previously but they are no longer supported due to the death of Flash.

Comment: **Very** related but unsolved: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52701307/video-embedding-inside-beamer-without-adobe-flash-player

Comment: http://vesta.informatik.rwth-aachen.de/ftp/pub/mirror/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/media4svg/example/beamer-example-1.svg

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz This will work pretty well. I am still hoping for an answer that keeps everything in one file because the people I am presenting too will be upset when I send them several .svgs, but if you upload an answer and nothing else comes up for a while I'll mark it.

Answer (score 0):

> the following example is taken from the answer https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/595106/36296 thus I'll post this as community wiki

One can use the `media4svg` to produce svgs with embedded media like movies etc.

```
\documentclass[dvisvgm,hypertex,aspectratio=169]{beamer}
\usepackage[british]{babel}

\usefonttheme{serif}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{media4svg}
\usepackage{menukeys,siunitx,calc}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% PageDown, PageUp key event handling; navigation symbols <--, -->
% mouse cursor autohide on idle
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage[totpages]{zref}
\usepackage{atbegshi}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepgflibrary{arrows.meta}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\def\navBtnSize{9pt}
\def\navBtnLnWd{1.6pt}
\AtBeginShipout{%
  \AtBeginShipoutAddToBox{%
    \special{dvisvgm:raw
      <style>svg{cursor: none}</style>%
      <defs>%
      <script type="text/javascript">%
      <![CDATA[%
        var svgRoot=document.getElementsByTagName('svg')[0];%
        var cursorTimer;%
        document.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e){%
           e.preventDefault();e.stopPropagation();%
           svgRoot.style.cursor='initial';%
           if(e.target!=svgRoot){%
             e.target.style.cursor='inherit';%
           }%  
           try{clearTimeout(cursorTimer);}catch(err){};%
           cursorTimer=setTimeout(function(){e.target.style.cursor='none';},3000);%
        });%
        document.addEventListener('keydown',function(e){%
          if(e.key=='PageDown'||e.key=='ArrowDown'||e.key=='ArrowRight'){%
            \ifnum\thepage<\ztotpages
              document.location.replace('\jobname-\the\numexpr\thepage+1\relax.svg');%
            \fi%
          }else if(e.key=='PageUp'||e.key=='ArrowUp'||e.key=='ArrowLeft'){%
            \ifnum\thepage>1
              document.location.replace('\jobname-\the\numexpr\thepage-1\relax.svg');%
            \fi%
          }%
        });%
      ]]>%
      </script>%
      </defs>%
    }%
  }%
  \AtBeginShipoutUpperLeftForeground{%
    \raisebox{-\dimexpr\height+0.5ex\relax}[0pt][0pt]{\makebox[\paperwidth][r]{%
      \color{structure!40!}%
      \ifnum\thepage>1%
        \href{\jobname-\the\numexpr\thepage-1\relax.svg}{%
          \tikz{
            \filldraw[black!0!] (-1pt,-\dimexpr\navBtnSize/2+1pt\relax)
              rectangle (\dimexpr\navBtnSize+1pt\relax,\dimexpr\navBtnSize/2+1pt\relax);
              \draw[{Straight Barb[round]}-,line width=\navBtnLnWd] (-1pt,0)--(\navBtnSize,0);}}%
      \else%
        \textcolor{lightgray}{\tikz{
          \filldraw[black!0!] (-1pt,-\dimexpr\navBtnSize/2+1pt\relax)
            rectangle (\dimexpr\navBtnSize+1pt\relax,\dimexpr\navBtnSize/2+1pt\relax);
            \draw[{Straight Barb[round]}-,line width=\navBtnLnWd] (-1pt,0)--(\navBtnSize,0);}}%
      \fi\hspace{0.5ex}%
      \ifnum\thepage<\ztotpages%
        \href{\jobname-\the\numexpr\thepage+1\relax.svg}{%
          \tikz{
            \filldraw[black!0!] (-1pt,-\dimexpr\navBtnSize/2+1pt\relax)
              rectangle (\dimexpr\navBtnSize+1pt\relax,\dimexpr\navBtnSize/2+1pt\relax);
              \draw[-{Straight Barb[round]},line width=\navBtnLnWd] (-1pt,0)--(\navBtnSize,0);}}%
      \else%
        \textcolor{lightgray}{\tikz{
          \filldraw[black!0!] (-1pt,-\dimexpr\navBtnSize/2+1pt\relax)
            rectangle (\dimexpr\navBtnSize+1pt\relax,\dimexpr\navBtnSize/2+1pt\relax);
            \draw[-{Straight Barb[round]},line width=\navBtnLnWd] (-1pt,0)--(\navBtnSize,0);}}%
      \fi%
      \hspace{0.5ex}%
    }}%
  }%
}%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\title{Presentation example with embedded video}
\subtitle{Use a Web browser and press \keys{F11}}
\author{AlexG}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}
\selectlanguage{british}

\begin{frame}[fragile]
\titlepage\footnotesize
\makebox[0.3\linewidth]{\hrulefill}\\[1ex]
Navigate with \keys{PageUp} \& \keys{PageDn}, toggle Full-Screen with \keys{F11}.\\[2ex]
To build this presentation from the source, run:\vspace{-2ex}
\begin{verbatim}
dvilualatex beamer-example
dvilualatex beamer-example
dvisvgm --bbox=papersize --font-format=woff2 --zoom=-1 --page=- --output=%f-%0p.svg \
                                                                     beamer-example
\end{verbatim}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[fragile]{Video file}
  Embedded local video file from package \emph{mwe}
\begin{verbatim}
\includemedia[width=24em,height=13.5em]{}{example-movie.mp4}
\end{verbatim}
  \begin{center}
  \includemedia[width=24em,height=13.5em]{}{example-movie.mp4}
  \end{center}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[fragile]{Remote video}
  Video streamed from URL
\begin{verbatim}
\includemedia[width=24em,height=13.5em,url]{}{%
https://interactive-examples.mdn.mozilla.net/media/cc0-videos/flower.webm}
\end{verbatim}
  \begin{center}
    \includemedia[width=24em,height=13.5em,url]{}{https://interactive-examples.mdn.mozilla.net/media/cc0-videos/flower.webm}
  \end{center}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[fragile]{Player control}

The standard player controls (option `\verb+controls+') take a lot of space of the media display. Therefore, it is not recommended to enable them. Nevertheless, interactivity is still provided through touch or left mouse button click, and through the keyboard as summarized in the table.

Click on the media display to start playback. To pause playback, press the left mouse button on the media display. Release it to resume playback. To pause playback permanently, press the left mouse button on the media display and move the mouse out while keeping the button pressed.

\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\linewidth}
  \rule{1ex}{0pt}\\
  \begin{tabular}{ll}\hline
  Command & Shortcut\\\hline
  \rule{0pt}{2.4ex}Toggle Play/Pause & \keys{\SPACE}\\
  Increase volume & \keys{\arrowkeyup}\\
  Decrease volume & \keys{\arrowkeydown}\\
  Unmute audio & \keys{Ctrl+\arrowkeyup}\\
  Mute audio & \keys{Ctrl+\arrowkeydown}\\
  Toggle Full-Screen & \keys{F11}
  \end{tabular}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\linewidth}
  \rule{1ex}{0pt}\\
  \begin{tabular}{ll}\hline
  Command & Shortcut\\\hline
  \rule{0pt}{2.4ex}Seek back \SI{1}{\percent} & \makebox[\widthof{\keys{\SPACE}}][l]{\keys{\arrowkeyleft}}\\
  Seek forward \SI{1}{\percent} & \keys{\arrowkeyright}\\
  Seek back \SI{10}{\percent} & \keys{Ctrl+\arrowkeyleft}\\
  Seek forward \SI{10}{\percent} & \keys{Ctrl+\arrowkeyright}\\
  Seek to beginning & \keys{Home}\\
  Seek to end & \keys{End}
  \end{tabular}
\end{minipage}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

to be compiled with

```
dvilualatex filename
dvilualatex filename
dvisvgm --bbox=papersize --font-format=woff2 --zoom=-1 --page=- --output=%f-%0p.svg filename
```

and then open `filename-1.svg` in your favourite browser, e.g. Chrome, Firefox, ...